# THREE JS Shadow Issues

Tags: three.js, shadow

I’ve got a “flag” animation going and as the cloth material flaps in the wind and sorta folds unto itself I want it display shadows on itself - check out the fiddle to see what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/gilomer88/zfa9eLbo/38/

I've set both of my lights to castShadows as follows:

```
light1.castShadow = true;
```

and my “flag” object is set to receive shadows:

flagMesh.receiveShadow = true;

but I'm not getting any shadows on the flag itself - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your fiddle and it seems that on your light variables (light1, light2) you wrote:

```
light1.castsShadow = true;
```

instead of:

```
light1.castShadow = true;
```

This helped show some sort of shadow, but it looked
[like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZWmE.png).
This looks like shadow artefacts. What you can do about them is change the **bias** of the LightShadow with a small value. In the case of your fiddle, seems like the light that casted this shadow is *light2* so you can change it's bias value like so:

```
light2.shadow.bias = -0.0001;
```

And of course you can play around with positive values as well see what looks better, play around with light positions, etc.

Comment: Hey you're right! I did misspell the code there.  And I tried the `bias` statement you suggested - it does sorta work, but it ain't pretty, is it?  Weird. Why is this so hard to do? Thanks either way!